# Why I can not insert or update valid data after Instead of Trigger has been fired?

Tags: sql-server

Here is my simple test trigger transactions:
First, I designed a table:

```
CREATE TABLE T2_Score (
 UserID INT Primary key,
 Months INT,
 Score INT
);
```

Then, create an instead of trigger to set the restractions to make sure the value of Months should be between 1 and 12.

```
CREATE TRIGGER T2_Score_Months_Restriction
ON T2_Score
INSTEAD OF UPDATE, INSERT
AS
IF ((SELECT Months FROM inserted) > 12)
BEGIN
    PRINT ('Month must be between 1 and 12!')
ROLLBACK TRAN
END
```

But, the issue is I can not insert any valid values if the trigger has been fired once.
For example:

```
INSERT INTO T2_Score VALUES (11,15,18);
```

And inserted filed if I try the valid value(No warning notes, but file to insert value into table), for example:

```
INSERT INTO T2_Score VALUES (11,12,18);
```

Can someone explain why and how to modify my code? Thanks!!

Comment: Your code looks a lot like SQL Server code.  Why does the question have the MySQL tag?

Comment: Oh, you are right, I will remove it. Thank you, and apologize for my careless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That trigger will never insert any rows. It is an INSTEAD OF trigger that doesn't have any INSERT statement.

You need:

```
CREATE TRIGGER T2_Score_Months_Restriction
ON T2_Score
INSTEAD OF UPDATE, INSERT
AS
    IF (SELECT MAX(Months) FROM inserted) > 12 BEGIN    
        PRINT ('Month must be between 1 and 12!') ;
        ROLLBACK TRAN ;
    END 
    ELSE BEGIN 
        INSERT INTO T2_Score SELECT * FROM inserted ;
    END ;
```

Or perhaps:

```
CREATE TRIGGER T2_Score_Months_Restriction
ON T2_Score
INSTEAD OF UPDATE, INSERT
AS
    INSERT INTO T2_Score 
    SELECT * FROM inserted WHERE Months BETWEEN 1 AND 12 ;
```

The second versions allows partial inserts.

```
INSERT INTO T2_Score VALUES ( 4, 4, 4 ), ( 13, 13, 13 ); 
-- With the first trigger, this will insert 0 rows.
-- With the second trigger, this will insert 1 row.
```

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't it be *much* simpler to use a constraint?

```
CREATE TABLE T2_Score (
   UserID INT Primary key,
   Months INT,
   Score INT,
   CONSTRAINT CHK_MONTHS_1_12 CHECK (Months BETWEEN 1 AND 12)
);
```

Comment: Yep, that is a good idea, thx Gordon. But, I just want to practice my Trigger skills lol. But, sometimes, as a SQL developer at junior level, I may not consider about the constraint at the very beginning when I creat a table. So, instead of modify the table structure, I prefer using Trigger to perfect it.

Answer (score 0):

The instead of trigger does not work in MySQL. You can use a BEFORE INSERT and BEFORE update and abort the action:

```
CREATE TRIGGER T2_Score_Months_Restriction 
ON T2_Score
BEFORE INSERT,UPDATE 
AS
IF ((SELECT Months FROM inserted) > 12)
BEGIN
    DECLARE msg VARCHAR(255);
    IF (SomeTestToFail = "FAIL!") THEN
        set msg = "Month must be between 1 and 12!";
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = msg;
    END IF;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `INSERT` will be ecexuted atomically. It will succeed as a whole, or it will fail as a whole. You might be able to work around that by just deleting invalid values from `inserted`, but I don't recommend it.

It's a really bad idea to allow a SQL statement to partially succeed when part of it fails.